# Activate localstorage in socket.io

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

I want to use localStorage in my socket io project.I want to implement localStorage in my js file,but when i node my js file it says to me that localStorage is not defined.Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is tagged as node.js so I will assume you're trying to use `localStorage` on the server.   That will not work.  `localStorage` is a browser feature and is something that exists only in the browser, not in your node.js server.

If you want to save information persistently on your server, then you would typically either write data to a file yourself or you would use some sort of datastore/database to persistently save information.  If you're trying to save information on behalf of a specific user, then express-session in combination with a data store can save user sessions persistently.

If you are trying to use it in the browser and having problems there, then show us the actual code you're using that generates the error.